# How can I get all substrings matching a regex from another string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string: `"C:/This/is/a/windows/path/file20110312name20120221.csv"`.

I want to extract all dates (e.g. `[0-9]{8}`).

Generally, how can I extract sub-strings matching a pattern from a bigger string?

Comment: Well, have you read `?regex` and the help files linked under "see also"?

Comment: This was indeed in seealso but not ?regex... => ?grep

Comment: Looks like you learned a valuable lesson on finding functions ...

Comment: yep... actually I am not a newbie in R so It also means that the search for functionality process might need improvement, but I guess this is a hard problem for the R guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*It is advised to supplement your question with a reproducible example ([How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269))*

Is this what you look for ?

```
s <- "C:/This/is/a/windows/path/file20110312name20120221.csv"
regmatches(s, gregexpr("[0-9]{8}", s))
```

Comment: Yes exactly that ... where does this regmatches come from... ?

Comment: `regmatches()` was added in R 2.14.0.

Comment: can't find it on ?regex or ?grep though, this is going to cost me some points but thanks at least I learnt something

Comment: look in the @seealso section of ?grep... I agree it is not that easy to find, I was glad when I did !

Comment: damn ! Indeed ! thanks mate this stuff is so usefull !